# Redis - glob - like pattern with substring excluded

Tags: redis

I would like to define the following glob-like pattern for redis **KEYS/SCAN** commands:

```
prefix:[^excludedPart]:suffix
```

so that the following will match:

```
prefix:any:sufix
```

but this won't:

```
prefix:excludedPart:sufix
```

Is it possible to create such pattern?
Is it possible to exclude not only one character but longer substring?
I searched [here](https://redis.io/commands/KEYS) but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First - never use `KEYS` in production...

Secondly, you can Lua your way around this pickle. E.g. https://github.com/itamarhaber/redis-lua-scripts/blob/master/scanregex.lua

Thirdly, but only if you're really bored, you can try and develop a module that does that. There existing work on how to implement a [blocking `KEYS`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/modules/helloblock.c#L139) as well [using regex for `KEYS`](https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/redex#pkeys-pattern).

Happy hacking :)